# How to selectively disable CSRF check in Play Framework 2 (Java)

Tags: java, facebook, security, playframework, playframework-2.0

In Play Framework we can apply global CSRF check

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@Override
public <T extends EssentialFilter> Class<T>[] filters() {
    Class[] filters = { CSRFFilter.class };

    return filters;
}
```

Which is fine in most of the cases. But I want to setup Facebook Canvas page which points to our website. The thing is Facebook sends POST request to our site and it is prevented by the CSRF check. It always return **"Invalid CSRF Token"**

So I want to selectively disable CSRF check in some actions say www.ourwebsite.com/canvas

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a blog post on how to do this, see here:

http://dominikdorn.com/2014/07/playframework-2-3-global-csrf-protection-disable-csrf-selectively/

2017-Update: Starting with PlayFramework 2.6, this is now included in the Framework itself: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaCsrf#applying-a-global-csrf-filter

Comment: Do you have a Java version of this answer?

Comment: I.e. one where `Global` is written in Java and not Scala.

Comment: why do you need it in java? as seen in the blog post, u can use this functionality also from java controllers.

Comment: I guess I don't *need* it, but my `Global` is just written in Java already and I wouldn't know how to rewrite it in Scala (or it would, at least, take a lot of time for me to do so, since I don't know Scala very well).